# php foreach loop, not able to assign values to proper variable names?

Tags: php, foreach

I need some help with the foreach loop.  Say I have this method:

```
public function showPaymentDetails() {

    $data = array("name"             => $this->name,
                  "lastname"         => $this->lastname,
                  "email"            => $this->email, 
                  "company"          => $this->company,
                  "event_name"       => $this->event_name,
                  "event_price"      => $this->event_price,
                  "uniqid"           => $this->uniqid,
                  "mobile"           => $this->mobile,
                  "travel"           => $this->travel,
                  "job"              => $this->job,
                  "how_hear"         => $this->how_hear,
                  "geusts"           => $this->guests,
                  "slider_network"   => $this->slider_network,
                  "slider_invest"    => $this->slider_invest,
                  "slider_investors" => $this->slider_investors,
                  "gender"           => $this->gender
                  );

    return $data;

}
```

Now i want to assign each value of an array to a variable. This is what I do:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $row[$i]) {
    $row[$i];
    $i++;
}

echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
```

As you can see I am assigning values to `$row[]`. Which is really bad. How can I assign those values to such variable names as `$name`, `$lastname` etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should describe what you want to do ... sounds incorrect anyway.

Comment: `extract($data);`?  http://php.net/extract  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why assign them to variables? You already have an array with named keys. That's more efficient than separate vars.

Comment: What is `$data as $row[$i]` supposed to do?  Maybe you just want `$row = array_values($data);`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't need to loop in the array, you can just assign variables using your array and scopes with keys

```
$data =  showPaymentDetails();
$name = $data['name'];
$lastname = $data['lastname'];
//and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
```

that would then turn `$this->name` into `$name`.  However this is **very bad practice**.  You are better of just accessing the variables like

```
$data['name'];
$data['lastname'];
//Etc
```

Comment: By the way you are missing a paranthesy in your foreach

Answer (score 1):

Variable variables is what you described, however I would just use the `$data` array and not assign to individual variables:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
```

Also, `extract($data);` is the same result.

A closer look at your code has me wondering, why in the world you are building an array in a class function that is comprised of already existing object vars just to transform them into standalone vars?  Bad design so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract them within the current scope:

```
extract(showPaymentDetails());

echo $lastname;
```

See also: [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract)